# What is the difference between p2p interface address and p2p device address

Tags: wifi-direct, wifip2p

I am trying to  understand if both p2p interface address and p2p device address are same. I see some where saying

> A P2P Device shall only use a P2P Interface Address for communication
>   within a P2P Group. All other communication between P2P Devices shall
>   use the P2P Device Address

Can someone help me with this query.

Answer (score 0):

P2P device address is global one, but P2P interface address is locally administrated.(i.e) Whenever you join a P2P group you will get interface address for your device. Since you got the interface address, you will use the interface address within  the P2P group till the group exists. Once the group is expired, you cannot use the same interface address, you will get new one again whenever you join the group.

During Discovery and find phase, you will use the P2P device address but once you joined the group you will use only P2P interface address.

For more information, refer Wi-Fi P2P Technical Specification v1.2